# device.drawuserprimitive asking for explicit type

Tags: c#, xna

hi im trying to get my code working, its to draw a primitive cube in xna.

i keep getting an error

> Error 1   The type arguments for method 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.PrimitiveType, T[], int, int)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

```
public void RenderShape(GraphicsDevice device, Effect effect)
    {
        BuildShape();

        foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            effect.Parameters["xTexture"].SetValue(topTexture);
            pass.Apply();
            device.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionNormalTexture>(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, shapeVertices[2], 0, 2);

            effect.Parameters["xTexture"].SetValue(bottomTexture);
            pass.Apply();
            device.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionNormalTexture>(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, shapeVertices[3], 0, 2);

            effect.Parameters["xTexture"].SetValue(frontTexture);
            pass.Apply();
            device.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionNormalTexture>(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, shapeVertices[0], 0, 2);

            effect.Parameters["xTexture"].SetValue(backTexture);
            pass.Apply();
            device.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionNormalTexture>(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, shapeVertices[1], 0, 2);

            effect.Parameters["xTexture"].SetValue(leftTexture);
            pass.Apply();
            device.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionNormalTexture>(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, shapeVertices[4], 0, 2);

            effect.Parameters["xTexture"].SetValue(rightTexture);
            pass.Apply();
            device.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionNormalTexture>(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, shapeVertices[5], 0, 2);
        }

    }
```

i thought adding the  was defining the type explicitly....but apparently not.

Comment: How did you declared `shapeVertices`?

Comment: private VertexPositionNormalTexture[] shapeVertices;

and

shapeVertices = new VertexPositionNormalTexture[36]; in my build shape method

Comment: i fixed it, rewrote half my code, i was writing stuff using xna 3.1 in xna 4.